# NoCaptcha returning error invalid-json

Tags: php, json, recaptcha

I integrated Googles funky ReCaptcha NoCaptcha into a simple html5 form.
On localhost it is working, but testing online it always returns the error 'invalid-json'. Here is part of my code:

```
$secret = 'TEHSEHCRET';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
// do some
}
else {
print_r($errors = $resp->getErrorCodes());
}
```

Returns `Array ( [0] => invalid-json )`

I googled for some help but found nothing really helpful.

Since the code on- and offline is the same I am really clueless where the problem is coming from. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify says nothing about the error code. Guess the solution is too simple.

Comment: if you need more code just scream and i'll deliver! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key to the solution was to simply turn on the php errors (I know, it's embarrassing). This delivered the error that kept me struggling and also delivered the solution at the same time:

PHP had problems connecting to the https verifying page of google. That was just because of a single option in the php.ini: allow_url_fopen

php.net description:

> allow_url_fopen boolean
>
> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing
> URL object like files. Default wrappers are provided for the access of
> remote files using the ftp or http protocol, some extensions like zlib
> may register additional wrappers.

Changing its value from 0 to 1 solved my problem. Shows even more how important it is to turn on php errors when developing (I am a super noob to php programming)

Hope this helps somebody some time!

Comment: Thank you man. It helped me to realize what is actually wrong. I used https://github.com/google/recaptcha with sockets method. Thanks again

Comment: You are absolutely correct. `allow_url_fopen` needs to be true. Or you can use `$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());` --> That always works.

Answer (score 56):

I had the same issue and fixed it by using cURL as request method instead POST.

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
```

Comment: It must be `$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());`

Comment: I can verify that, it must be `CurlPost`. Also, it solved the problem for me too.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this fix.  On my dev system, the OPs code works, but on my client's system I need the CurlPost.  What is the issue that his corrects?  Fixes with no explanations make me nervous.

Comment: I had the same problem and the curlPost() worked, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too. I would really like to know why. It took me forever to find this.

Comment: I faced this issue today, in my case my hosting provider blocked some of the ports! due to some security reasons. after unblocking it works fine!

Comment: @BlackBurn027 What ports specifically?

Comment: This was long back i think it was TCP ports 20 - 22

Comment: This worked, but also setting `allow_url_fopen` to enabled, as in other post.

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me:

```
//$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);

// If file_get_contents() is locked down on your PHP installation to disallow
// its use with URLs, then you can use the alternative request method instead.
// This makes use of fsockopen() instead.
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using reCAPTCHA PHP client library < 1.2.4 with `SocketPost` request method then you need to update to ≥ 1.2.4 or you should switch to `CurlPost` because the Google server response has changed: https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/359

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same issue. I was fixed this issue by replacing 'SocketPost' with 'CurlPost'.

**Replaced**

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());
```

**With**

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
```

Answer (score 1):

// Make the call to verify the response and also pass the user's IP address

```
  $resp = $recaptcha->verify($recaptcha_response, $this->CI->input->ip_address());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha;
use ReCaptcha\RequestMethod;
use ReCaptcha\RequestParameters;
use ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost;

class NotSSLCurl extends CurlPost implements RequestMethod
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->curl = curl_init(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9999);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST , 1);
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    }

    public function submit(RequestParameters $params)
    {
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , $params->toQueryString());
        return curl_exec($this->curl);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        curl_close($this->curl);
    }
}

// example validation:
$recaptcha = new ReCaptcha('CLIENT_SECRECT', new NotSSLCurl());
$resp      = $recaptcha->verify(@$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
var_dump($resp->isSuccess());
```

Answer (score -1):

the response is a json object. it should be decoded first. i am pretty new to web programming/development, but i successfully integrated google recaptcha on an asp.net test site which does nothing for now, but i'm sure it handles the json response just the way i want it to..

found another, could [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-Google-RECaptcha-on-Client-Side-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx) help.

Comment: So I finally tried it last night. Starting with the fact, the this tut is using a slightly older version of ReCaptcha I thought I might give it a chance anyways. It still did not work; I didn't even got any errors. phew

Comment: sorry, the codes i used for my test were in asp.net and c# on back end, i dont know how on ajax.. but, i think you have to deserialize the json object.. and then parse the resulting string response..